# Issues feeding forms into HTML. Error when using <div> tags

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a form to be fed onto my HTML page and then use  tags to edit the layout. It will take information from my database and have it displayed in a form in the form of a value.

I am having constant issues with it saying that I have syntax errors. It happens everytime I add a div tag into the feed.

I have tried many things, but the only thing that gets this code to work consistently is when I take out all  tags.

At this point, I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. Any help would be appreciated

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- information -->

<body>

    <div class="feedContainer" id="nfeed">
    </div>

    <script src="managePosts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
var db = firebase.firestore();

const HTMLFEED = document.getElementById("nfeed");

//works
db.collection("trips").where("flag", "==", true).where('userID', "==", /*localStorage.getItem('userID') */ "101010101").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {

        var fullName = doc.data().fullName;



        HTMLFEED.innerHTML += " \

                    <form> \
                        <img src='circleProfile.png' alt='User photo'> \
                        <div class='name'> <p>" + fullName + "</p></div>\
                        <div id='updatingForm'> \


                    </form>";

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a backslash to every line, even the empty ones.
You could also just remove the empty ones, but the best solution I could think of would be to use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
HTMLFEED.innerHTML += ` 
                    <form> 
                        <img src='circleProfile.png' alt='User photo'> 
                        <div class='name'> <p>${fullName}</p></div>
                        <div id='updatingForm'> 
                    </form>`;
```